# How to install ruby gem puma on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Welcome, gather around.

My first step when trying to install the gem puma is to enter gem install puma --version 2.12.3 into my command prompt. Then this error appears. I don't know what to make of it.

```
C:\Users>gem install puma --version 2.12.3
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150809-8352-14jkju1.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-puma_http11-dir
        --without-puma_http11-dir
        --with-puma_http11-include
        --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
        --with-puma_http11-lib
        --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
        --with-cryptolib
        --without-cryptolib
        --with-libeay32lib
        --without-libeay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2
.12.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
/puma-2.12.3/gem_make.out
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Contents of the mkmf.log here

Comment: http://notepub.com/#buttons=hidden&name=freshlikeuser123

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need OpenSSL, but be warned that some gems just fail to work on Windows.

https://github.com/hicknhack-software/rails-disco/wiki/Installing-puma-on-windows

Comment: I've followed these same steps previously and it screwed my bundler up completely and still wasn't able to get puma..So not sure where to go from here. But I will try again one more time.

Comment: I receive this error C:\Users>gem install puma -- --with-opt-dir=c:\
openssl
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
        127: The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/r
uby/2.2.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try posting contents of `mkmf.log`, maybe someone will be able to help you than.